# I am using list of checkbox value to filter data in django

Tags: django

I am trying to filter the data in a tabular form using AJAX and JQUERY in django
only the filter data by "ram" isn't working, although when an AJAX call is made the GET request is send to the server but the model filter query doesnt run;
But when I run the following model filter query in shell it works

```
allproduct = allproduct.filter(Memory__in=ram_list)
```

django app name "graphicsCard"
This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Products
# Create your views here.

# is the filter query correct 
# def is_valid_queryparam(param):
#     return param != '' and param is not None

# the function that handles filters
def productViews(request):
    allproduct = Products.objects.order_by('-Memory', '-Core_Speed', '-Boost_Clock')

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'Boost_Clock_min' in request.POST:
        Boost_Clock_minimum = request.POST.get('Boost_Clock_min')
        allproduct = allproduct.filter(Boost_Clock__gte=Boost_Clock_minimum)

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'Boost_Clock_max' in request.POST:
        Boost_Clock_maximum = request.POST.get('Boost_Clock_max')
        allproduct = allproduct.filter(Boost_Clock__lte=Boost_Clock_maximum)

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'Core_Clock_min' in request.POST:
        Core_Clock_minimum = request.POST.get('Core_Clock_min')
        allproduct = allproduct.filter(Core_Speed__gte=Core_Clock_minimum)

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'Core_Clock_max' in request.POST:
        Core_Clock_maximum = request.POST.get('Core_Clock_max')
        allproduct = allproduct.filter(Core_Speed__lte=Core_Clock_maximum)

    # print(request.GET.getlist('ram'))
    # ram_list = request.GET.getlist('ram')
    if request.method == 'GET' and 'ram[]' in request.GET:
        ram_list = request.GET.getlist('ram[]')
        # ram_list = list(map(int,ram_list))
        ram_list = [int(i) for i in ram_list]
        print(ram_list)
        allproduct = allproduct.filter(Memory__in=ram_list)


    print(str(allproduct.query))
    context = {
        'product': allproduct,
        'Manufacturer': Products.objects.all().distinct(
            'Manufacturer').order_by('Manufacturer'),
        'Memory': Products.objects.all().distinct(
            'Memory').order_by('Memory')
    }
    return render(request, 'Products.html', context)
```

In the python interpreter when I run the server the "ram_list" shows the value but the products dont get filtered out.

The model.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Architecture = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    Boost_Clock = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Core_Speed = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Memory = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Memory_Speed = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    Memory_Bandwidth = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    DVI_Connection = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    Dedicated = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    Direct_X = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    HDMI_Connection = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    Integrated = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    L2_Cache = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    Manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    Max_Power = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    Memory_Bus = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    Memory_Type = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    Power_Connector = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)#this field should be remained unchanged
    Process = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    Resolution_WxH = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True, null=True)
    SLI_Crossfire = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True, null=True)
    url_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The urls.py inside the "graphicsCard"

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.productViews, name='products'),

]
```

The urls.py of the project

```
from django.contrib import admin
#from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include, path
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('calc.urls')),
    path('cards/',include('graphicsCard.urls')),
]
```

The template "products.html"

```
{% extends 'homepage.html' %}
<!-- Attach all those files that such Jquery UI after adding 
the features of filtering;
The basic one should be considered first [Similar to flipkart]
    The user selects all the features regarding they want
    to filter and then we can click a submit button to
    make an AJAX call. -->

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
        <!--  Header row under Navbar  -->    
    <div class="col-12 bg-primary py-3">
        <h1 class="pageTitle text-center">Choose A Video Card</h1>
    </div>
    <!--  SideBar  -->
    <div class="col-2 bg-info">
        <form action="." method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <!-- Min and max value of Boost Clock -->
            <h3>Boost Clock</h3>
            <input type="number"  class="form-control" id="blockContentMin" placeholder="min" name="Boost_Clock_min" value="0">
            <input type="number"  class="form-control" id="blockContentMax" placeholder="max" name="Boost_Clock_max" 
            value="2000">
            <p id="price_show" style="padding:10px;">0 - 2000 MHz</p>
            <div id="boost_clock_range"></div>

            <!-- Min and max value of Core Clock -->
            <h3>Core Clock</h3>
            <input type="number" value="0" class="form-control" id="viewCountMin" placeholder="min" name="Core_Clock_min">
            <input type="number" value="2000" class="form-control" id="viewCountMax" placeholder="max" name="Core_Clock_max">
            <p id="Core_show" style="padding:10px;">0 - 2000 MHz</p>
            <div id="Core_range"></div>
            <!-- ################This is resposive brands/Manufacturer section#########  -->
                <h3>Brand</h3>
                <div  style="height: 11.25ems; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
                    <div class="list-group-item checkbox bg-primary">
                        {% for manu in Manufacturer %}
                        <label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector brand" value="{{manu.Manufacturer}}">{{manu.Manufacturer}}</label>
                        <br>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- ################This is resposive Ram section#########  -->
            <h3>Memory</h3>
            <div  style="height:180px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
                <div class="list-group-item checkbox bg-primary">
                    {% for mem in Memory %}
                    <label><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector ram"
                            value="{{mem.Memory}}">{{mem.Memory}}</label>
                    <br>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" id="submit" class="col-6 btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>    
        <table class="col-10 table table-dark py-0 my-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 35%;">name</th>
                    <th>Architecture</th>
                    <th>Manufacturer</th>
                    <th>Boost Clock</th>
                    <th>Core Speed</th>
                    <th>Memory</th>
                    <th>Vote/Rating</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               {% for card in product %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ card.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{card.Architecture }}</td>
                        <td>{{card.Manufacturer }}</td>
                        <td>{{card.Boost_Clock}}</td>
                        <td>{{card.Core_Speed}}</td>
                        <td>{{card.Memory}}</td>
                        <td>N/A</td>
                    </tr>
               {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>

</div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                    filter_data();

                    function filter_data() {
                        var brand = get_filter('brand');
                        var ram = get_filter('ram');

                        $.ajax({
                            url: '{% url "products" %}',
                            method: "GET",
                            data: {brand: brand, ram: ram , },
                            success: function (data) {
                               console.log("Data was succesfully captured");
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    function get_filter(class_name) {
                            var filter = [];
                            $('.' + class_name + ':checked').each(function () {
                                filter.push($(this).val());
                            });
                            console.log(filter)
                            return filter;
                        }
                      $('.common_selector').click(function () {
                            filter_data();
                        });


                    $('#boost_clock_range').slider({
                            range: true,
                            min: 100,
                            max: 2000,
                            values: [100, 2000],
                            step: 50,
                            stop: function (event, ui) {
                                $('#price_show').html(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);
                                $('#blockContentMin').val(ui.values[0]);
                                $('#blockContentMax').val(ui.values[1]);
                                filter_data();
                            }
                        });

                    $('#Core_range').slider({
                            range: true,
                            min: 100,
                            max: 2000,
                            values: [100, 2000],
                            step: 50,
                            stop: function (event, ui) {
                                $('#Core_show').html(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1]);
                                $('#viewCountMin').val(ui.values[0]);
                                $('#viewCountMax').val(ui.values[1]);
                                filter_data();
                            }
                        });

                    });
        </script>

{% endblock %}
```

[server inputs and queryset transaction with client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VibE1.png)

Comment: What does ram_list get printed as?

Comment: ram_list gets printed as ['16384', '24576']

Comment: Every other filter is in the POST data, why is this filter in the GET? Is the method definitely a GET?

Comment: I will edit my answer by adding images of the server

Comment: And, how do you know the filter is not being run? What's getting rendered in `Products.html` that leads you to this conclusion?

Comment: It renders this code "allproduct = Products.objects.order_by('-Memory', '-Core_Speed', '-Boost_Clock')"

Comment: Just before the line `context = {` can you put this statement and share the output? `print(str(allproduct.query))`

Comment: the query without any filter when its executed for the first time

Comment: Can you add the output to the question?

Comment: I made posted an answer for the same

Answer (score 0):

`Products.Memory` is an `IntegerField`, you may have to cast the returned list of strings to integers

```
ram_list = map(int, request.GET.getlist('ram[]'))
```

I don't think the `[]` is required when calling `getlist` but this doesn't seem to be causing you any issues...

Comment: The reason why it is not rendering is because the "GET" request which is sent through ajax is constantly overlapped by "POST" request.

Answer (score 0):

the query without any filter when its executed for the first time

```
SELECT "graphicsCard_products"."id", "graphicsCard_products"."name", "graphicsCard_products"."Architecture", "graphicsCard_products"."Boost_Clock", "graphicsCard_products"."Core_Speed", "graphicsCard_products"."Memory", "graphicsCard_products"."Memory_Speed", "graphicsCard_products"."Memory_Bandwidth", "graphicsCard_products"."DVI_Connection", "graphicsCard_products"."Dedicated", "graphicsCard_products"."Direct_X", "graphicsCard_products"."HDMI_Connection", "graphicsCard_products"."Integrated", "graphicsCard_products"."L2_Cache", "graphicsCard_products"."Manufacturer", "graphicsCard_products"."Max_Power", "graphicsCard_products"."Memory_Bus", "graphicsCard_products"."Memory_Type", "graphicsCard_products"."Power_Connector", "graphicsCard_products"."Process", "graphicsCard_products"."Resolution_WxH", "graphicsCard_products"."SLI_Crossfire", "graphicsCard_products"."price", "graphicsCard_products"."url_name" FROM "graphicsCard_products" ORDER BY "graphicsCard_products"."Memory" DESC, "graphicsCard_products"."Core_Speed" DESC, "graphicsCard_products"."Boost_Clock" DESC
```

[query without filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRta7.png)

the query when I hit the filters checkbox of ram

```
SELECT "graphicsCard_products"."id", "graphicsCard_products"."name", "graphicsCard_products"."Architecture", "graphicsCard_products"."Boost_Clock", "graphicsCard_products"."Core_Speed", "graphicsCard_products"."Memory", "graphicsCard_products"."Memory_Speed", "graphicsCard_products"."Memory_Bandwidth", "graphicsCard_products"."DVI_Connection", "graphicsCard_products"."Dedicated", "graphicsCard_products"."Direct_X", "graphicsCard_products"."HDMI_Connection", "graphicsCard_products"."Integrated", "graphicsCard_products"."L2_Cache", "graphicsCard_products"."Manufacturer", "graphicsCard_products"."Max_Power", "graphicsCard_products"."Memory_Bus", "graphicsCard_products"."Memory_Type", "graphicsCard_products"."Power_Connector", "graphicsCard_products"."Process", "graphicsCard_products"."Resolution_WxH", "graphicsCard_products"."SLI_Crossfire", "graphicsCard_products"."price", "graphicsCard_products"."url_name" FROM "graphicsCard_products" WHERE "graphicsCard_products"."Memory" IN (12288, 16384, 24576) ORDER BY "graphicsCard_products"."Memory" DESC, "graphicsCard_products"."Core_Speed" DESC, "graphicsCard_products"."Boost_Clock" DESC
```

[query with filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olOP1.png)

Comment: I ran the query in PostgresSQL the query returns an accurate answer

Comment: Then it looks like it's working... Why do you say you are not getting the correct results when rendering?

Comment: I dont understand its not even throwing exception or errors

Comment: I believe the reason for this is because the GET request in the address bar says 
```"GET /cards/?ram%5B%5D=12288&ram%5B%5D=11264 HTTP/1.1"``` 
it is appending '%5B%5D' do we have some turn around for this

Comment: The query is fine, the issue is probably in your template? What is being rendered?

Comment: The rendered page shows the answer to "Products.objects.all()" and does not even refreshes or changes even after the AJAX call.

Comment: You don't do anything with the result of the AJAX call? You just log a success message